# Limit of a complex sum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

I need to  find the limit for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n |e^{ixk/n}-e^{ix(k-1)/n}|$$  Using Euler's formula and cosine of a sum this simplifies to $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\sqrt{2(1-\cos(x/n))}$$

I have a strong feeling that the limit should be $x$ but have no idea how to prove it. Can you help me please?

Comment: Taylor formula for cosine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has the Taylor expansion $\cos x=1-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$, so in particular for fixed $x$ we have
$$2(1-\cos(x/n))=\frac{x^2}{n^2}+O(n^{-3}).$$
Can you finish it off?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about using the cosine series.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that fix $x$
$$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\sqrt{2(1-\cos(x/n))}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\sqrt{4\sin^2(\frac{x}{2n})}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}2n|\sin(\frac{x}{2n})|=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}2n\frac{|x|}{2n}=|x|$$

**EDIT**

For the second last equality:

$\sin(x) = x +O(x^2)$ (By Tayler expansion around $0$, $\sin x = x - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + ...$)

Comment: $1-\cos x\neq\sin^2(x/2)$

Comment: Your coefficient is not correct.

Comment: @Clayton Good point, will update

Comment: @Jason Hmm.. actually could you indicate why they do not equal?

Comment: There we go. I would also add that your second last equality, while correct, is a little sloppy. But that may be a matter of preference.

Comment: @Jason Ah.. I get your point. Yes, I know I missed out a coefficient of $2$, but I missed the $2$ in the question's formula, instead of the $2$ when we expanding the cos function

Comment: I'll edit per your last comment @Jason

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:Note that $$e^{ ixk/n }-e^{ ix(k-1)/n }=1-{ e }^{ -ix/n }+{ e }^{ ix/n }-1+{ e }^{ 2ix/n }-{ e }^{ ix/n }+...={ e }^{ -ix/n }$$